# SQL: insert date automatically

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I was wondering how can I fill a column automatically in the database with the GETDATE() ?

Like when I open the database the date of that column should be GETDATE() automatically

Do you suggest using a constraint or a procedure? and what would be the query?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

**UPDATE**

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT contraint_name DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR column_name

Answer (score 0):

Adding a constraint should do the trick:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR column_name
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Read this**

> This alter cmd will fill all the value
>   in table with the current date time
>
> suppose if you have last year data in
>   the table for the same data current
>   date
>
> will be filled, so think and resolve,
>   read the **Default** constraints and
>   then use the cmd